# can't start the Xcode project on a physical device

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, device

I took courses on ios development and wants to run the application on my device, but it turns out such an error. What to do? Thanks in advance!

[image: screenshot]

Error:

> ".app/Frameworks/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises: stat() failed with errno=1"

Answer (score 0):

It seems when updating to iOS 13.3.1 Apple changed the behaviour of free apple developer accounts, no longer allowing them to use embedded frameworks.

The solution is to remove the use_frameworks! in your Podfile and replace it with use_modular_headers!

e.g.

```
target 'your_project_name' do
use_modular_headers!
pod 'RealmSwift'
```

end